# How to define basic open set in infinite product topology excluding a certain Lemma 3.8

Tags: general-topology, advice

Source: *A First Course in Topology by Robert Conover*

3.3 **Definition**

Let {$(X_\lambda, T_\lambda$):$\lambda \in \Lambda$} be a nonempty collection of nonempty topological spaces. The
**Product topology** on $X_\lambda$ is the topology generated by the the subbasis **{$\pi_\lambda^{-1}$($U_\lambda)$:$U_\lambda \in T_\lambda$}**

I would like to define a basic open set on the infinite product topology, but I can’t use the following Lemma cause I haven’t proved it .

I look through the site some were a bit to complex. Others
I could not use cause I would have to prove 3.8 which came
after this theorem.

I need it to prove a theorem.Most of the theorem is done.

The theorem is:

Let {$X_\lambda:$ $\lambda\in\Lambda$ }be a nonempty collection of nonempty sets
with |$\Lambda$|$\geq$$\aleph_0$. If $U_\lambda$ is open in $X_\lambda$ then $\Pi U_i $ is open in the product
topology on $\Pi X_i$ iff
$U_\lambda=X_\lambda$ for all but finitely many

**Here is the Lemma**

Let {$X_\lambda:$ $\lambda\in\Lambda$ }be a nonempty collection of nonempty sets
with |$\Lambda$|$\geq$$\aleph_0$. Then for $\lambda_1,…,\lambda_n\in\Lambda$ If $U_\lambda\subset  X_\lambda$ then
$\bigcap \pi^{-1}_\lambda$($U_\lambda)$=
$\pi_\lambda$ $A_\lambda$=
$U_\lambda if \lambda=\lambda_n$
otherwise
$X_\lambda $if $\lambda$ $\ne \lambda_n$

I have definitions of sub-basis and projection maps and the definition of
infinite product space

I was thinking to use the theorem
that if $B_\lambda$ $\in B$ is a basis. for
$T_\lambda$ for each $\lambda\in\Lambda$ then the collection{$\pi_{\lambda}^{-1}$($B_\lambda)$:$B_\lambda$ $\in B$ } is a subbasis  for the product topology

Comment: How do you define the product topology? The theorem that you are trying to prove, I know it as a definition for the product topology,

Comment: I noticed that in many other posts about product topology . In this text it is a theorem.  I will post the def. of product topology in the main post.